# CodeIgniter: Storing an image in the database?

Tags: mysql, image, codeigniter

I would like to store images in my mySQL database using the CodeIgniter PHP framework.
How do I write and read the image?

Thank you.

Comment: Learning is all good, just be careful not to shoot yourself in the foot with storing images directly in the database. You can learn from the mistakes of others. ;)

Comment: So I've been reading, and I guess I will go with simple image directory and storing the url as you suggested. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to use the **file uploading class** of CI to upload the files and use the **models** to save them to the database, here are related resources:

**[File Uploading Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html)**
**[Models](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html)**

Answer (score 3):

It's considered bad practice to store the actual image files directly in a database. Instead you can just store a path to the file in the database and store the file in a directory on the server.

[AstaHost Forums](http://www.astahost.com/Good-Practice-Store-Image-Binary-Files-Mysql-Database-t14738.html)

[Best approach for storing uploaded image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445267/best-approach-for-storing-uploaded-image)

[CodeIgniter - Uploading an Image through a form, store the location of the image in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288076/codeigniter-uploading-an-image-through-a-form-store-the-location-of-the-image)